# Replace categorical values with traffic light colors

Tags: r, icons, r-markdown, gsub

I have some categorical values I want to show in a table as red, yellow and green spots in R or r-markdown.

Is there a way to do this? maybe an icon package that will let me gsub text for an Icon? I have scoured the internet and come up empty handed. Any thoughts are appreciated.

```
library(kableExtra)
dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:6]
kable(dt) %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = F, font_size = 12) %>%
  row_spec(0, angle = -90)%>%
  row_spec(1:5, bold = F, color = "black")
```

[image]

Comment: you might try [`fontawesome`](https://github.com/rstudio/fontawesome).

Comment: also formattable:  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/formattable/vignettes/formattable-data-frame.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example that uses html format in knitr. It uses the `cell_spec` function to make a new column using an icon and colour.

```
library(kableExtra)
library(emojifont)
library(dplyr)

load.fontawesome()
options(knitr.table.format = 'html')

cylcols = function(cyl) {
    case_when(
        cyl == 4 ~ 'green',
        cyl == 6 ~ 'yellow',
        cyl == 8 ~ 'red'
    )
}

dt <- 
    mtcars[1:5, 1:6] %>% 
    mutate(symbol = fontawesome('fa-circle')) %>%
        mutate(symbol = cell_spec(symbol, 'html', color=cylcols(cyl))) %>%
        select(mpg, cyl=symbol, disp, hp, drat, wt)

kable(dt, escape = F) %>%
    kable_styling(full_width = F, font_size = 12) %>%
    row_spec(0, angle = -90) %>%
    row_spec(1:5, bold = F, color = "black")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be exactly what i was going for. However, I'm not able to reproduce your results. I'm getting colored square outlines, not filled circles. Copied your code over as is. not sure why i can't reproduce. Thoughts?

Comment: Difficult to say - did you successfully load the emojifont package and did the load.fontawesome call work?

Comment: yes to both, i also re-installed the emojifont package. no errors or warnings when i run it but still no success.

Comment: What do you get if you run this at the console `fontawesome('fa-circle')`

Comment: > fontawesome('fa-circle')
[1] ""

Comment: Are you using RStudio and which operating system are you running on?

Comment: yes, r studio. and windows 10. side question. how do you view a list of all the fontawesome icons? i might try some trial and error.

Comment: It should look like a circle in Rstudio - if not then that's where to focus

Comment: i tried it on two computers. one of which is new and R was installed 2 weeks ago so should be up todate. any thoughts on where I could go from here? Thanks for all your help.

Comment: On a Linux machine it works but I tried on a Windows 10 machine and I saw warnings like "font family not found". May be worth starting a new thread to keep the question and answers clean.

Comment: @AndrewChisholm If I already have a text column with the desired color is it necessary to run the cylcols = function? Ive tried with and without it for my data frame but I get either a blank column or html code

Comment: @k3r0 The `cylcols` function just translates a number to a colour so if you already have the colour then you won't need the function, just use the name of the column as the color argument in the call to `cell_spec`.

Comment: @AndrewChisholm I've tried that and every time I knit the document the column comes out empty :S this is a sample: structure(list(Revenue.Source = "Sales Revenue", Target = "Yellow",Revenue.Last.month = "$25,380.10 ", Revenue.Previous.month = "$29,769.70 ",Percentage.Change = "-14.75%", month = 8L), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-1L))     I have everything in my code the same way as the question except "mutate(symbol = cell_spec(symbol, 'html', color=Target))"

Comment: @kr30 I just tried my original answer on a Linux machine and it no longer works. Some package change has broken it. Not sure why. Suggest raising another question rather than having a difficult to follow comment thread.